# Populating input tags with data from Database

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a form setup that is able to edit products inside of my database. What I would like to do is have the input fields be populated with the information of the product that a user is trying to edit, instead of having to manually enter in ALL the information (basically being able to highlight the information) I am using Flask along with Jinja2 and WTForms.

Here is my code for the form:

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}
{% block container %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/product-edit.css') }}">
 <div class="top-pad" style="text-align: center;">
   <div class="well">
<div class="row" id="product-form">
  <h2 class="col-md-6" style="color: blue">Edit Product</h2>
</div>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('my_view.product_edit', key=category_id) }}" role="form" id="product-form">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form.brand.label }}: {{ form.brand() }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form.name.label }}: {{ form.name() }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form.price.label }}: {{ form.price() }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form.rating.label }}: {{ form.rating() }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <!-- Category Dropdown -->
        <label for="category col-md-6" id="category-select">Categories: </label>
          <select name="category" id="category">
            {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{ category[0] }}">{{ category[1] }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        <!-- END Category Dropdown -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form.year.label }}: {{ form.year() }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form.stock.label }}: {{form.stock() }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">{{ form.image.label }}: {{ form.image() }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not even sure I am stating my question properly, please let me know if I need to clarify more. I will try my best.

Comment: What's not working?  It's helpful to know what's not working, and what you would like to see instead.

Comment: fill form object with your data before you send it to template

Comment: @Jalepeno112 I'm not sure even where to start with this or how to go about doing something like this.